# Why Wordpress Gutenberg oEmbed return 404 or "oembed_invalid_url"

Tags: wordpress, oembed

I have wordpress deployed on subdirectory, like this:

1. example.com
2. example.com/blog

on number 2,
when i tried to embed video from youtube (i already check that video could be embed)
the oEmbed API give 404 when process it with message "oembed_invalid_url"

on number 1, it's ok when embed video

tried to check debug.log (activated that feature), but no logs written to that file espeacially for that process

I deploy it on VM with PHP-FPM and Nginx

is that because my subdirectory or else ?

update:

some screenshoot

[image]

[image]

Comment: The links from number 1 and 2 are the same in the headers? - probably the oembed url us changed in the number 2 example. Without see the url you're sending in number 2 example, it's difficult to pinpoint another possible causes...